# Distinction between number, digit, numeral

Tags: vocabulary, numbers

Here is my current understanding: 24 is a number, in which 2 and 4 are digits.

XIV is a Roman numeral, in which X, I and V are Roman numerals.

Could you please confirm that?

Context: effort to understand differences

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between 'number' and 'numeral'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392716/what-is-the-difference-between-number-and-numeral)

Comment: From sister site ELL: [What's the difference between a figure, a number and a digit?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265320/whats-the-difference-between-a-figure-a-number-and-a-digit)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142038/discussion-on-question-by-janko-n-distinction-between-number-digit-numeral).